# How to set auto reply for every incoming mail to an account in Exchange server?

Tags: exchange-2010

Exchange server sends a auto reply once to each sender by default if the auto reply option is enabled.

Is it possible to configure in  Exchange server 2010 such that it sends auto reply on every mail it receives if the auto reply option is enabled ?

Comment: Recepie for a mail storm if someone else has an auto responder. Don't you think?

Comment: Are you now using `Out Of Office` or a mail rule?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer is no, for the reason stated above: Dueling Out of Office Replies can bring down a couple mail servers with alarming quickness.

You may be able to replicate this behavior with a clever mail rule, but think about the above sentence before you try.

Comment: AFAIK Out of Office replies will not cause a mail storm.  Auto-Reply, however, could.

Comment: @Cheekaleak Indeed, Out-of-office replies are designed that way for that very reason.

Comment: I understand the consequences of such a setup. We have an application which response to clients automatically when there is a request, we want our application to come out of any email loop. So for testing we required that setup.